# Can we use "Not only, but too" instead of "Not only, but also,?

Tags: american-english, writing-style, conjunctions, formality

I am wondering about the use of "Not only, but too" instead of "Not only, but also.?
For example:

> The candidates campaigned not only in Perth but in Darwin too.

and is it formal to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Idiomatically:

The candidates campaigned not only in Perth but **also** in Darwin.

The candidates campaigned not only in Perth but in Darwin, **too**.

Note the position of the adverbs.

Comment: To be clear, also can also go at the end, but too HAS to be at the end